# Prove of addition in real numbers using Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x = A | B $ and $ y= C|D $ be cuts. There addition is
$$ E =\{r \in \mathbb Q , \, r = a + c, a \in A, c \in C \}$$
$$ F = Q - E \, \,\text {(rest of Q)} $$

I want to show $E |F$ is a cut.
$$E \cup F = \mathbb Q  $$
$$E \cap F = \varnothing $$
How can I prove that E does not have the largest element and $e \in E , f \in F \, then \, e < f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, suppose towards contradiction that $E$ has a greatest element $e$. Then, by definition, $e=a_0+c_0$ with $a_0\in A$ and $c_0\in C$. Since $A,C$ are Dedekind's cuts, there are $a_1>a_0$, $c_1>c_0$ s.t. $a_1\in A, c_1\in C$. Then, clearly, $a_1+c_1>a_0+c_0=e$, contradiction.

For the second part, if $e\in E$ and $r<e$, then  $e=a_0+c_0$ with $a_0\in A, c_0\in C$. Since $r<e$, we have $r=e-x$, for some $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. It follows that  $r= (a_0 +c_0) -x = a_0 + (c_0 -x) $. Since $C$ is a Dedekind cut, $c_0 -x\in C$ and therefore $r\in E$.